# Should git lfs tracking by pattern done by every user that clones the repository?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I created a git repository with LFS enabled (by default on bitbucket). Cloned it to my local machine and setup up git lfs tracking locally using patterns. Finally, I pushed the `.gitattributes` file to the repo. My questions is that all the other users who have access to this repository, do they have to do this all over again (setup patterns etc.)? or cloning `.gitattributes` file is sufficient for them to start using LFS storage?

Comment: If `.gitattributes` is in the tree of the repository (which it is) then I don’t see why they would need to do it themselves. On the other hand, if it was inside `.git/` then they would need to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified with another user who cloned the repository that was already setup with pattern matching in `.gitattributes` file of the repository. The user did not have do put the patterns in again.